# How to create HBbase Compound filters in java

Tags: java, filter, hbase

I understood that from the HBase shell it is possible to create compound filters like `(Filter1 AND Filter2) OR (Filter3 AND Filter4)`.

Ref: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html

But in java I only found `FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL` and `FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE` operators to define how filters will be processed.

In my case I'd like to define a Scan which will perform some `QualifierFilter` only on some specific rows using `RowFilter`.

ex: if rowkey contains "$today", filter out the Column Families having the Qualifier "number_eggs_produced because it is too early. Else do not filter it.

`(!RowFilter) OR (RowFilter AND QualifierFilter)`

For the moment I found 2 bad workarounds :

- I started to write a Customer filter but probably it is already supported as the shell must call java code and I don't see it.
- I filter manually the data in the results :

  ```
      ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
      for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next())
      {
          for (Cell cell : result.listCells())
          {
              String row = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneRow(cell));
              long qualifier = Long.valueOf(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell)));
              double value = Double.valueOf(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell)));

              if(row ... )
  ```

I hope I'm clear.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FilterList` is composable.  The two different operators let you create `AND` lists and `OR` lists.  For example:

```
FilterList andFilter = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
FilterList orFilter = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(orFilter);
orFilter.addFilter(rowFilter1);
orFilter.addFilter(andFilter);  // composition

andFilter.addFilter(rowFilter2);
andFilter.addFilter(rowFilter3);
```

This is the logical equivalent of `(rowFilter1 || (rowFilter2 && rowFilter3))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm ! I don't think I would got it by myself.

Comment: yes it would be less confusing if the operators were `AND` and `OR`, but they are thinking from the perspective of filters.